# Unmanaged VPS Backup Technique

Tags: backup, vps

Is it worth backing up an un-managed VPS? The technology seems to be so stable that crashes seems not likely to happen.

If so, what would be the best approach? I have read about backing up on the VPS itself but isn't this a nonsense? If the server would somehow crash I would end up without the server AND the backup itself..!

Comment: Please, banish from your mind all thoughts like "*it's so stable, there could never be data loss*" - we could tell stories that would turn your hair white.  The only question you should **ever** ask about backups is "*how much would it cost me if I lost this data*".

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by an unmanaged VPS?

Comment: I have a couple of VPS's which I have bought and I have handled installation and updates. The provider will offer a template OS from which to start from and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

So you only back up for crashes? No hardware failures or user errors ever occur? Please tell me you are not responsible for data in a company setup.

> If so, what would be the best approach?

RTFM - the documentation of your virtual host technology. VPS backup is trivial from the host level and supported by every visualization technology ever produced for commercial use.

Comment: No that is not the case. These VPS have just been setup recently. I do consider all options when backing up. The issue is that I am new to VPS technology. I have always worked with traditional physical servers and I ALWAYS do extensive backups!

Comment: Maybe the question has been phrased the wrong way..?

Comment: `The issue is that I am new to VPS technology. I have always worked with traditional physical servers and I ALWAYS do extensive backups!` - Virtual servers and physical servers are no different in regards to your need to provide disaster recovery, business continuity, backups, restores, data security, etc., etc. You seem to have the idea that a VPS is somehow different in those regards. What would you do regarding backing up a physical server? Do the same for your virtual server.